# How to test Node API with DB data?

Tags: node.js, testing, express, mongoose

I'm coming from Rails world,
On rails I used FactoryGirl to create some db data before testing api.
I've searched on the web for similar methods and I couldn't find any good results.

How do you test your API if you want to insert some db data before?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/factory-girl :))

Comment: @stdob-- , I've already saw it, but it seems to me that it's not widely used, So I tried to search for more widely used options.